# dynamic json visualisation of nested child nodes of unknown schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visualization

I have a JSON string (read from a file) that i would like to visualization the web page.

The JSON has nested children, some nested deeper than others, 200,000 objects total.

I need some way of visualizing this complex json so the user can expand and close nodes and delete nodes and their children.

Is there any native .net components or open source components that are common for this use and is can somebody use below to demo their use?

```
    {"Files":
    {
      "list_of_files": [
        "testfile.txt",
        "textfile2.txt"
      ],
      "folder1":
       {
        "list_of_files": [
          "test.txt"
        ]
       },
        "folder2": {
          "list_of_files": [
            "test1.txt",
            "test2.txt"
          ], 
     "folder2_folder1":
       {
        "list_of_files": [
          "test.txt"
        ]
       }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes you can do this kind of thing with JSON.net

Comment: Would you have an example of hpw to use this with example json in question?

Comment: What kind of insight you want to have from that data? It is all about folder structure or something else?

Comment: Good question, i want to simply allow the user to follow the folder structure to a particular place or file. If they want to select a node and delete that node then they can and the UI will update

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious solution would be to use some sort of a tree view. You tagged SO with ASP.NET and there is asp:TreeView component but given very large size of your collection I would discourage you from using it, as the page size would probably be enormous (maybe the component supporst virtualization, not sure though)
Instead you should go for client side visualization. I would advice tree view for angular

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

Angular is pretty simple to learn and with it's MVVM architecture it'd be easy for you to virtualize data so you don;t need to load all of on the start.

Other option is to user silverlight, but that's kind of limiting.

Comment: ok, i'll check it out. ideally i was hoping for a asp.net, javascript, ajax combo solution but i take your point on the file size. I was thinking of purging this by removing unnecessary info as early as possible

Comment: it all comes down to if you can add new items siblings only when the parent is opened, which I don't suppose is a case for asp.net as it (at best) reloads whole components. This is why I advice you to go with angular, the beauty here is that you can add, remove nodes in runtime and the view is updated automatically without you having to do anything.